# EDID signal with DVI Splitter

Tags: hardware, resolution, monitor, splitter, edid

I have a computer and two monitors (with different sizes and resolutions) and I want to connect them to the PC via a DVI Splitter.

My question is: how do you define the "signal" EDID in this setup?

The splitter has a main output (which sends the EDID) and secondary (that fits)? Or EDID signal is taken by monitor with lower performance?

Comment: I'd recommend migrating this to Superuser as questions about general software and hardware that aren't specifically used for programming are off-topic here.

Comment: You're right, sorry. Now I open a discussion in the correct section.
Thank you!